# Serve static file for all sub-routes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I build an MVC Core application with single-page-clients.

I have configured some routes for `/api/...` which works well. Additionally I want to serve static files for some routes. e.g.:

- For **all** sub-routes of `/Home/` I want to receive `/Home/index.html`
- For **all** sub-routes of `/App/` I want to receive `/App/index.html`

I added `app.UseStaticFiles()` to `Configure()` so I can access `/Home/index.html` but it does not work for any other sub-route.

What is missing?

Comment: If you are using asp.net core 2.0 try Razor pages for static pages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/index?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Ahmar I know Razor Pages, but I do not see how it helps me. I get a tool-generated HTML file and would like to avoid extra Controllers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my routing-system to attribute routing. Among others I added a `HomeController`:

```
[Route("")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Route("")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); // The Home-page
    }

    [Route("Error")]
    public IActionResult Error()
    {
        // show an error page
        return Content(Activity.Current?.Id?.ToString() ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier.ToString());
    }

    [Route("{client}/{*tail}")]
    [Produces("text/html")]
    public IActionResult ClientApp(string client, string tail)
    {
        // show a client app
        try
        {
            return new ContentResult()
            {
                Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"./wwwroot/{client}/index.html"),
                ContentType = "text/html"
            };
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("/Error");
        }
    }
}
```

My client apps have had an `index.html` file inside its own folder (`client` routing-part) inside of `wwwroot`. When a request tries to access `/something/...` the route of `ClientApp` matches with `something` as the client-app folder name and the `index.html` is sent to the client. There is no redirect and the url stays the same.

It causes no problem with static files if you add `UseStaticFiles` **before** `AddMvc` in `Startup`:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMvc();
```

Tested in *ASP.NET MVC Core 2.0*.